# Understanding .begin and .end in vectors

Tags: c++, vector, auto

I'm learning vectors from [this post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-in-cpp-stl/) and they start off with iterators. They define .begin and .end as follows:

> begin() – Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the vector
>
> end() – Returns an iterator pointing to the theoretical element that
>   follows the last element in the vector

And then they give the following code snippet, I added the 3rd for loop to express my question.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

int main() {
    std::vector <int> g1; //creating a vector
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
        g1.push_back(i);
    }
    std::cout << "Output of beginning and end values: ";
    for (auto i = g1.begin(); i != g1.end(); i++) {
        std::cout << *i << " "; 
    }
    std::cout << "\nOutput of beginning and end addresses: ";
    for (auto i = g1.begin(); i != g1.end(); i++) {
        std::cout << &i << " ";
    }
     //"Output of beginning and end values: 1 2 3"
     //"Output of beginning and end addresses: 0105FB0C 0105FB0C 0105FB0C"
    return 0;
}
```

My confusion is that the address of `i` stays the same, but the value that `i` has changed. Doesn't `i*` mean `i` is just dereferenced? So something has to be changing the value of `i` if it's address is not changing so that it would be able to have a different value. I think I may be confusing iterators with pointers. I know that `auto` is basically type inference but that's about it.

So my question is, how does the value of `i` change, if it's address is the same for every element in the vector?

Comment: `i` is an iterator, which acts "like" a pointer.  It contains a handle of some sort (could be a pointer, could be an index) which can be used to (a) move through the collection and (b) location the current element of the collection.  If you looked at `g1[i]` and `&i` in the first loop, would you still have the same questions?  If not, why?

Comment: Imagine if `i` was just a `int*`. It may help understand what is happening. Note that unlike other containers, `T*` is a valid iterator type for `std::vector<T>` so the comparison is pretty accurate.

Comment: "*So something has to be changing the value of `i` if it's address is not changing so that it would be able to have a different value*" - that would be the `i++` statement in the loop. It advances the iterator to refer to the next element in the vector

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`&i` is the address of the local variable `i`.  This will not change.  `*i` dereferences the iterator, and returns the value at that element of the vector.  `&*i` will return a pointer to the element in the vector.

So you loop should use

```
std::cout << &*i << " ";
```

to see the addresses change.

Comment: Thank you! I see the addresses changing but they're 4 bytes apart. i.e. 00F6E3B8 00F6E3BC 00F6E3C0.  Is that because an ```ìnt``` occupies 4 bytes by default?

Comment: @S.Ramjit Yes, an `int` is 4 bytes on your system.  Other systems may have a different size.

Answer (score 3):

To make it more clear consider a similar code but instead of a vector there is used an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    for ( auto p = std::begin( a ); p != std::end( a ); p++ )
    {
        std::cout << "The address of p is " << &p
                  << ", its value is " << p
                  << ", and the pointed value is " << *p
                  << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
The address of p is 0x7ffcaf6a6830, its value is 0x7ffcaf6a683c, and the pointed value is 1
The address of p is 0x7ffcaf6a6830, its value is 0x7ffcaf6a6840, and the pointed value is 2
The address of p is 0x7ffcaf6a6830, its value is 0x7ffcaf6a6844, and the pointed value is 3
```

This part of the outputted strings

```
The address of p is 0x7ffcaf6a6830
```

is not being changed because it is the address of the local variable (pointer) p itself.

This part of the strings

```
its value is 0x7ffcaf6a683c
```

is being changed because within the loop the value of the pointer is changed

```
for ( auto p = std::begin( a ); p != std::end( a ); p++ )
                                                        ^^^^
```

In each iteration the pointer points to the next element of the array.

This part of the strings

```
and the pointed value is 1
```

is also being changed because there is outputted the pointed value due to dereferencing the pointer.

The same things take place with the iterator of a vector.

Answer (score 2):

> I think I may be confusing iterators with pointers

Well, pointers are iterators, so this is understandable. But not all iterators are pointers. In other words, non-pointers can also be iterators.

> I know that auto is basically type inference but that's about it.

In this case, the type is deduced to be `std::vector<int>::iterator` because that is the type that `std::vector<int>::begin` returns.

> So my question is, how does the value of i change, if it's address is the same for every element in the vector?

The value of `i` is changed by the `i++` in the loop. The address where an object is stored never changes through the lifetime of the object. Regardless of whether the type of that object is pointer, some other iterator or not an iterator at all.